# How to use Environment.NewLine as an optional parameter default value

Tags: c#, optional-parameters, compile-time-constant

I prefer `Environment.NewLine` over `"\r\n"` whenever possible, even though this project is Windows-only. I was wondering if there was a way to use it as a default value of an optional parameter.

Consider the extension method

```
public static string ToSummaryString<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> items, 
    string delimiter = Environment.NewLine)
```

and the compile time error

> Default parameter value for 'delimiter' must be a compile-time constant

I tried using parameter attributes too, with a similar fate

```
public static string ToSummaryString<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> items, 
    [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(Environment.NewLine)] string delimiter)
```

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

So is there any workaround? Or are my only options to hard-code it to `"\r\n"`, or make it required?

Comment: Can you use `null` as the default value and switch to `Environment.NewLine` inside the method when the argument is `null`?

Comment: You can always do it "the old way": write 2 methods; one with the delimiter and one without.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace your default value with `Null` and then use [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator), inside your method. Something like this:

```
public static string ToSummaryString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string delimiter = null)
{
    var realDelimiter = delimiter ?? Environment.NewLine;
}
```

As an alternative, you can also use [Method-Overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/member-overloading), as [@Dennis_E](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53840892/2946329) also mentioned: *write 2 methods; one with the delimiter and one without*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the best way to do this would be to have the default value be null, then check for that value in the method.  If the parameter is null, set the default value to "\r\n."  Better yet, have that default value be in a resource file so that you can change it as needed without having to recompile the app.  (Putting the value in a config file works as well, of course)

Comment: Paired with some good XML documentation to help with intellisense, this might work i.e. `/// <param name="delimiter">Default value is really Environment.NewLine</param>`. The comment would break down if the default were configurable however, but that's past the scope of my question anyway. Thanks!